# Why is one lamba expression with operator working and not the other

Tags: c#, lambda, operators

I have a WPF project with a datagrid named dataGrid.

I'm doing some testing to see how lambda expression and operators are working.

Here are the data I have in my table tUsers:

[image]

And I don't understand why this:

```
this.dataGrid.ItemsSource = (from em in context.tUsers
                             select new { em.name }).ToList();
```

This will work and display the proper names in the datagrid. It looks like this:
[image]

But if I do like in the tutorial on [.codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33769/Basics-of-LINQ-Lamda-Expressions):

```
this.dataGrid.ItemsSource = (from em in context.tUsers
                             select em.name).ToList();
```

This will just display some integers instead of the names. I don't know why.
[image]

So I guess that the first one will create an anonymous object and put em.name inside. But I don't understand one one would work and not the other.

I'm particularly interested in why it displays those integers.

Could anyway explain?

PS: I just noticed that the interger are actually the length of the string. I don't know why though.

Comment: Haven't used WPF, but I would imagine the source is looking for an object with a property `name`, and if not found, defaults to something else (possibly index?). Anyway, the statements you have are very different to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid shows a column for every non-indexer property of the type of enumerable you pass to it.

In the first case you pass a list of an anonymous type which has a single `name` property, which is a string, so it displays a single column called `name` and displays those strings.

In the second case you pass a list of strings, and strings have a single `Length` property, so it creates a single column called `Length` and displays those lengths.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing 2 syntaxes :

```
this.dataGrid.ItemsSource = (from em in context.tUsers
                         select new { em.name }).ToList();
```

It will create a list of string (i.e. the names you are looking for)

And this :

```
this.dataGrid.ItemsSource = (from em in context.tUsers
                         select em).ToList();
```

It will create a list of your object "employee".

**Edit :**
By default, DataGrid auto generates columns from given item class, so it will search for properties in String class that it can convert into column. So here, it displays the string.Length.
So you need to create your own column and turning off AutoGenerateColumns. Example :

```
<DataGrid Name="MainGrid" ... AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="name" Binding="{Binding}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Look for Projection Operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.dataGrid.ItemsSource = (from em in context.tUsers
                         select em.name).ToList();
```

This will return a list of Strings, whereas the other one will select a list of anonymous type, with a name property.

It displays the Length of each String, why it defaults to this behavior, I don't know though.